# How i can disable or hide NetBeans service information into Output Window?

Tags: netbeans

I can't find this option! Pls help. I wish to disable information into red box on screenshot.

[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In0oX.png)

I look in "Compile on Save" but it disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finded the solution. The "Compile on Save" option must be active (you need the plugin install).
[Screenshot with solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiytD.png)